# Runtime error R6016 - Not enough space for thread data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I just got the error message "R6016 - Not enough space for thread data" in a simple MessageBox window as I closed my application. It's a .NET 4.0 WPF application that does use multiple threads and a few (4 at most) `[ThreadStatic]` fields. I think I can remember having seen this error message one or two times before, during the last year on any computer. The error is not reproducible at all. Maybe I will see it again if I automatically start and close my program a few thousand times?

After reading about the error message itself, thread-local storage (TLS) in Windows, the corresponding Windows API functions and how the .NET JIT might use it, I'm not sure what exactly happened and how I might have caused it with my application.

The application sets the thread pool size to minimum 20 threads on startup. This is the total expected maximum I ever need (usually I need around 10). I don't start more than 1 or 2 separate threads. When I last observed this error, the application did almost nothing and I closed it after a few seconds, so the thread pool can't have grown that much. Also, as far as I understand TLS slots, the number of threads is irrelevant. It's that number of fields which eat precious TLS slots.

Where should I start searching for the bug?

Comment: Hmya, how many threads to do you start when you **close** your app?  Something imploded pretty badly here, the more bizarre the behavior, the more untrustworthy and bizarre the error message.  You cannot get help with this here, record a minidump and call Microsoft Support.

Comment: The application sets the thread pool size to minimum 20 threads on startup. This is the total expected maximum I ever need (usually I need around 10). I don't start more than 1 or 2 separate threads. When I last observed this error, the application did almost nothing and I closed it after a few seconds, so the thread pool can't have grown that much. Also, as far as I understand TLS slots, the number of threads is irrelevant. It's that number of fields which eat precious TLS slots.